# Proof of Sufficiency of Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I understand that the Cauchy-Riemann equations $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$ are *necessary* for a complex function to be complex-differentiable, but I would like to see a proof that they are also *sufficient* for this to be true. I am assuming that these partial derivatives exist and are continuous everywhere that they are satisfied.

Comment: They aren't. You also need conditions on the partial derivatives involved (continuity, for example). Note that, for example, $f(x+iy) = x^2$ satisfies the equations at $z=0$, but is not analytic. The general sufficient conditions are either rather complicated or not actually known, depending on who you ask. Either way, your question needs a more precise formulation.

Comment: Is there an example of a function that is not complex-differentiable at a point where the C-R equations are satisfied and the partial derivatives exist and are continuous?

Comment: No, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let be provide some inspiration based on linear algebra.

Remember in multivarible culculus, we always deem derivative as a linear mapping, or more concretely, a matrix. Now let's apply it in the case of complex linear space.

Let $f$ be a complex function on $ \mathbb{C} $, then $f$ is homolophic at point $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ if and only if $Df(z_0)$ is a complex linear map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C} $. Then identify $i$ to a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, i.e., we deem $i$ as a complex linear map which rotate the plane 90 degrees anticlockwise. Next,  $Df(z_0)$ is a complex linear map if and only if $Df(z_0)$ commutes with $i$(think it why?), i.e., $Df(z_0)=\begin{pmatrix}
u_x & u_y \\
v_x & v_y
\end{pmatrix}$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
u_x & u_y \\
v_x & v_y
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
u_x & u_y \\
v_x & v_y
\end{pmatrix}$$

if and only if $u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x.$

Comment: An more interesting thing is that by the same way you may find $f$ is anti-homolophic at point $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ if only if $u_x=-v_y, u_y=-v_x.$ at point $z_0$

Comment: Oh wow, that's really insightful. Thank you for that.

Comment: Sorry, let me fix my previous comment: $f$ is anti-holomorphic at point $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ if only if $u_x=-v_y, u_y=v_x$ at $z_0$. Hint: In this time, the condition is $Df(z_0)i=-iDf(z_0)$. @JacksonFitzsimmons

Answer (score 1):

A function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ represents a complex-linear map (with respect to the standard complex-linear structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $i\cdot(u,v) = (-v,u)$) iff its matrix with respect to the standard $\mathbb{R}$-basis has the form $\begin{pmatrix}
a & -b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}$ (easy exercise). If $f(x,y) = (u(x,y),v(x,y))$ is $C^1$ then its derivative (again in the standard basis) is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
u_x & u_y \\
v_x & v_y
\end{pmatrix}.$

Now note that $f$ is complex-differentiable at a point if and only if it is real-differentiable there and its derivative is a complex-linear map. (Proof: $f$ is complex-differentiable at $z$ with $f'(z) = a \in \mathbb{C}$ if and only if $f(z+h) = f(z) + ah + o(h),$ and any $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ has the form $h \mapsto ah$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}.$) Combining this with the remarks above we see that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is complex-differentiable if and only if it is real-differentiable and its real and imaginary parts satisfy the C-R equations. In particular if $f$ is of class $C^1$ then $f$ is complex-differentiable if and only if its real and imaginary parts satisfy the C-R equations.

Answer (score 0):

The integral around every single triangle is zero by Green's theorem. If the integral around every single triangle is zero then the function is complex differentiable by Morera's theorem. Done.

Comment: But now I have to see a proof of Morera's theorem, thank you though. I am new to complex analysis.

Comment: "If the integral around any triangle is zero, then$\ldots$" is ambiguous: it could mean "If there is any triangle around which the integral is zero, then$\ldots$".  But "If the integral around every triangle is zero" is unambiguous. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: can i recommend Priestley's Introduction to Complex Analysis?